Get company name from account id or campaign id in linkedin ad API
Please let us know if is there any LinkedIn Ad API available which we can use to get the company information by passing the account id or campaign id.
I tried calling below linked ad analytics api by using MEMBER_COMPANY pivot value for the specific campaigns, but this is not giving result:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/ads-reporting/ads-reporting?view=li-lms-2024-05&tabs=http
